# Multiple Table Column alignment in iTextsharp

Tags: c#, alignment, itext, tabular, pdfptable

I am creating a table where each column has its own alignment as shown below. How do I accomplish it at column level than at cell level?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iText and iTextSharp don't support column styles and formatting. The only way to do this is as you are doing currently, cell by cell.

**EDIT**

The easiest work around is to create helper methods that set your common properties. These can either be done through extension methods or just regular `static` methods. I don't have a C# IDE in front of me so my sample code below is in VB but should translate fairly easily.

You can create a couple of quick methods for each alignment:

```
Public Shared Function CreateLeftAlignedCell(ByVal text As String) As PdfPCell
    Return New PdfPCell(New Phrase(text)) With {.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT}
End Function
Public Shared Function CreateRightAlignedCell(ByVal text As String) As PdfPCell
    Return New PdfPCell(New Phrase(text)) With {.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT}
End Function
Public Shared Function CreateCenterAlignedCell(ByVal text As String) As PdfPCell
    Return New PdfPCell(New Phrase(text)) With {.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER}
End Function
```

Or just a single one that you have to pass in one of the known constants:

```
Public Shared Function CreatePdfPCell(ByVal text As String, ByVal align As Integer) As PdfPCell
    Return New PdfPCell(New Phrase(text)) With {.HorizontalAlignment = align}
End Function
```

Then you can just do the following:

```
Dim T As New PdfPTable(3)
T.AddCell(CreateCenterAlignedCell("Hello"))
```

Comment: Oh! Sad to hear that. I will end up creating so many objects now!

Comment: Chris, are you fully aware of that or should I wait for other answers?

Comment: @Reddy S R, I would consider myself a pretty advanced iTextSharp user so I can say with a fair amount of confidence that my answer is correct. That said, I'm always finding new things out so there's always a chance that something exists that I don't know about. If you want you can wait a couple of days and see if anyone knows of a better solution. But it shouldn't be too hard to implement what you want with a little extra code, I'll update my post above.