# Creating array of cells in itextsharp for VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, itext

I am trying to create a pdf with a table with each cell having lots of different properties (i.e. border widths and text font, etc.) so instead of having to write out the code 500 times fore each individual cell I want to have an array of cells. I have the following code:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports System.IO

Public Class pdfQuote
    Dim cell() As PdfPCell
    Dim table As New PdfPTable(7)
    Dim n As Integer = 0

    Public Sub createNewQuote()
        newCell("test")
    End Sub

    Public Sub newCell(text As String)
        n += 1
        cell(n) = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(text))
        table.AddCell(cell(n))
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see you initializing the `cell` array.

Comment: @mkl I did with: Dim cell() As PdfPCell. I copied the code directly from another array of comboboxes that I had and the comboboxes array works.

Comment: *I did with: Dim cell() As PdfPCell* - that declares the variable but does not  instantiate the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make your life easier switch from an array to `List`. By doing that you don't need to keep track of the current index.

```
Public Class pdfQuote
    Dim cells As New List(Of PdfPCell)
    Dim table As New PdfPTable(7)

    Public Sub createNewQuote()
        newCell("test")
    End Sub

    Public Sub newCell(text As String)
        cells.Add(New PdfPCell(New Phrase(text)))
        table.AddCell(cells.Last)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT**

Also I'd recommending creating some helper methods so that you can share as much code as possible. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6918883/231316) has a simple example of that.

Comment: How do I change cell border widths and other cell attributes now. cells.BorderWidthRight for example is not a member of Systems.Collections.Generic.List(of iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell)